# Bootstrap CSS not loading with Grav on web server

Tags: css, themes, grav

I have installed the Bootstrap Grav theme to my site's web server but the standard css won't load - any thoughts?  It worked locally but when I re-install everything I still have this issue

https://github.com/getgrav/grav-theme-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing the Bootstrapper plugin as I believe the Botostrap Grav theme is no longer supported and was replaced by it